# Deploy RestEasy war in JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, resteasy

I try to deploy a simple hello world Rest (with resteasy resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.0.GA).

And I have an error during the deployment, that I can't solve.

Is someone knows/understands the deep cause ?

```
09:42:52,544 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/myrestcontext
09:42:52,621 ERROR [[/myrestcontext]] Exception starting filter Resteasy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:37) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3246) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3843) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at     org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.0.0.Final]

    at [.. super stack trace ..]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resteasy.logging.impl.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger
    at org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:92) [:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.<clinit>(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:38) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 83 more
```

[... some logs ...]

```
2017-08-30 09:43:32,019 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] (Thread-2) Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/myrestcontext" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/SG_cmprod/middleware/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/myglobalapplication/tmp/vfs/automount92d2521d1eaf7c08/myrestcontext.war-e002aea6358d931/ deployment failed

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87)
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Hope for some help !

Comment: Looks like you have  log configuration problem.  Figure out which framework you need to use and exclude the others.